# Top bar moves back and forth slightly while scrolling

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

While scrolling up and down, the top bar shifts back and forth by a couple of pixels. I noticed this because it gave the appearance that my hat was moving back and forth, but the hat is actually staying in the same position and the image is just moving behind it.

> [image: moving mustaches]

I'm using Chrome on iPad. Zooming is used for better visibility. Issue is present for 100% scale factor as well.

Comment: So the bug isn't actually hat related, just top bar related... Maybe focus more on the actual issue and try not to incorporate the irrelevant thing into it too much? That only makes it harder for the right people to find it.

Comment: Does it do it in safari? IIRC apple insists on their rendering engine, so it may not be chrome either.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek can’t reproduce in Safari.